# Nginx rewrite omitting port

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've got a an nginx setup that's proxying all requests to a rails app. I would like to have a some kind of "maintenance-mode", so that if I use a different nginx-config, all incoming requests should return a local `maintenance.html` page.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
server {
        listen      3000;
        server_name localhost;
        root    html/;          #maintenance.html resides here

        location / {
            # redirect everything not already going to maintenance.html
            if ($request_uri !~ ^.*/maintenance.html$ ) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
            }
        }
}
```

With this setup, I am able to directly access `http://localhost:3000/maintenance.html`. However, if I trigger the rewrite rule, the new URL results in `localhost/maintenance.html` instead of `http://localhost:3000/maintenance.html`.

This results in a completely empty page being rendered.

nginx version: `nginx/1.0.6` on Windows 7

thx for any help

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed, it works fine with Internet Explorer and also with Chrome. Only Firefox seems to have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location / {
  try_files /maintenance.html $uri =404;
}
```